# ReadFile has return ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA

Tags: c#, .net

GetLastError return 1453 ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA after ReadFile. Does it means that there are memory leak or something? This code is used to communicate with usb device. This procedure works for a 10 hours (read every 40 ms) of testing and then error comes.

```
uint ReadBytesCount = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[0x8000];
fixed (byte* p = bytes)
{
    if (UnsafeMethods.ReadFile(handle, p, 0x8000, out ReadBytesCount, intOverlapped) == 0)
    {
        int hr = UnsafeMethods.GetLastError(handle);
        if (hr == UnsafeMethods.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
        {
            doCleanup = true;
            break;
        }
        if (hr == NativeMethods.ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            int error = 0;

            // if we get IO pending, MSDN says we should wait 
            // on the WaitHandle, then call GetOverlappedResult
            // use timeout to ensure that first time read
            bool success = waitReadEventWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
            if (success)
            {
                uint ReadInProgressCount = 0;
                success = UnsafeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(
                           handle,
                           intOverlapped,
                           ref ReadInProgressCount,
                           false);
                if (!success)
                    error = UnsafeMethods.GetLastError(handle);
                ReadBytesCount += ReadInProgressCount;

                if (!success && error != 0)
                {
                    // Ignore ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE, because there's a chance 
                    // one of those while shutting down
                    if (!(
                        (error == UnsafeMethods.ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE)
                        && ShutdownLoop)
                        )
                        Debug.Assert(false, 
                       "GetOverlappedResult,might leak intOverlapped memory"
                       + error.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        else if (hr != UnsafeMethods.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
        {
            // ignore ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errors. 
            Debug.Assert(false, "ReadUsbLoop returned error " + hr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `File.ReadAllText` method? Why unsafe code?

Comment: UnsafeMethods wraps api to a custom usb driver FTD2XX.DLL; I am using overlapped read/write because of performance requirements

Comment: If you change the code to use `File.ReadAllText` just for debug sake, what error do you get?

Comment: It is a streaming device aka sound, this error just popup after this code was executed probably a few thousand or more times successfully

Answer (score 0):

The only meaningful info i have found was in mysql bugs list [unconditional exit(1) on ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA 1453 (0x5AD) for InnoDB backend](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47055).

> When the error occurs, the SQL Server worker yields for 100ms and tries the read
>   operation again. This loop continues until the I/O is successfully issued. 
>   A simplified example demonstrates this behavior.

```
WHILE(      FALSE == ReadFile() 
    && (1450 == GetLastError() ||  1453 == GetLastError()) 
)
{
    Yield(100);
}
```

That lead me to conclusion that I should try sleep thread for 100 ms and retry read.

```
uint ReadBytesCount = 0; 
byte[] bytes = new byte[0x8000]; 
fixed (byte* p = bytes) 
{ 
    if (UnsafeMethods.ReadFile(handle, p, 0x8000, out ReadBytesCount, intOverlapped) == 0) 
    { 
        int hr = UnsafeMethods.GetLastError(handle); 
        if (hr == UnsafeMethods.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) 
        { 
            doCleanup = true; 
            break; 
        } 
        if (hr == NativeMethods.ERROR_IO_PENDING) 
        { 
            // do something
        }
        else if (hr == UnsafeMethods.ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA ||
                 hr == UnsafeMethods.ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        else if (hr != UnsafeMethods.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) 
        { 
            // ignore ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errors. 
            Debug.Assert(false, "ReadUsbLoop returned error " + hr); 
        }
    } 
}
```

**Update**: No, it did not help. Now I am considering throwing timeout error and reopening a device